# Installing and using nvidia drivers inside lxc container

Tags: xorg, opengl, lxc, xserver

I am not sure if this is possible or not but thought to ask the experts here.

So assuming that I am running `lxc` privileged container on `Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS`.
I have `nvidia` graphics card on my hardware. On host `Ubuntu`, I can install `nvidia` drivers and run our gaming application. it works fine.

But now I was thinking to segregate the development environment of our game into `lxc` container. Inside this container, I will install `nvidia` drivers that our gaming application uses.

But at the same time I do not want to install anything on host `ubuntu`. This means that the host will run `Xserver` with its default opensource nvidia driver called `nouveau`.

Is this configuration possible ? Our gaming app inside the container will use the host `Xserver` to create and draw into a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the blog and wiki at:

https://blogs.igalia.com/itoral/2014/07/29/a-brief-introduction-to-the-linux-graphics-stack/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager

I think it is not possible to have this configuration. I will have to have same graphics libraries installed in lxc container as the one on the host machine so as to use the same DRM/DRI layer of the kernel.